# Implement notification in angular 5

Tags: php, angular, laravel-5, onesignal

I have web application which uses php laravel as backend and angular 5 as frontend. I need to implement push notifications on my application. I have been using 'OneSignal' for notifications. Accordingly I used the web custom code in angular, but I need to know that is there any way that I could call my php web service as soon as I receive the notification. How would I come to know in angular that I have received a notification so that I could call my web service?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45354914/4129348 

hope it will help you

Comment: You could use websockets for - near - realtime two way communication between the backend and the angular app. But they are a real pain in the a** xD

Comment: Well, create an Observable. You can then use the third option that triggers the callback after successful operation.