# Integrating OneSignal with Angular don't register

Tags: angular, push-notification, push, onesignal

I'm trying to integrate OneSignal into my Angular web app to receive push notifications. I get to initialize the app, but dont register users in onesignal.

I have tested from localhost and from the url of the https app.

This is my OneSignal init code:

```
oneSignalInit(): void{

    const OneSignal = window['OneSignal'] || [];
    console.log('1. Init OneSignal');

    OneSignal.SERVICE_WORKER_PARAM = { scope: '/assets/js/' };
    OneSignal.SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = '../assets/js/OneSignalSDKWorker.js';
    OneSignal.SERVICE_WORKER_UPDATER_PATH = '../assets/js/OneSignalSDKUpdaterWorker.js';

    OneSignal.push(['init', {
        appId: 'b04d011c-5691-4f89-8037-5da301c47a7c',
        autoRegister: false,
        allowLocalhostAsSecureOrigin: true,
        notifyButton: {
          enable: false
        }
      }]);
      console.log('2. OneSignal Initialized');
      OneSignal.push(() => {
        console.log('3. Register For Push');
        OneSignal.push(['registerForPushNotifications']);

        OneSignal.getUserId().then((userId) => {
            console.log('4. User ID is', userId);
          });             
      });
      OneSignal.push(() => {
        OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', (isSubscribed) => {
          console.log('The users subscription state is now:', isSubscribed);
          OneSignal.getUserId().then((userId) => {
            console.log('4. User ID is', userId);
          });
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: I have been following this post ----> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347362/integrating-onesignal-with-angular

Comment: Hi! Did you solve you issue? Or you still need help?